# ssl - Update one of the certificates under an alias

Tags: ssl, certificate, keystore, keytool

I am trying to update a certificate in a keystore on server side by keeping the same alias as before, and under this alias there are actually 3 different certificates and I'd like to update only one of them.

They're like :

```
Alias name: alias
Creation date: 
Certificate chain length: 3
Certificate[1]:
Owner:......
...
Certificate[2]:
...
```

I tried first with this:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias <same_as_before> -file new.cer -keystore <same_as_before>.jks
```

but get exception:

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Failed to establish chain from reply
```

then I removed the old alias by using:

```
keytool -delete -alias <same_as_before> -keystore <same_as_before>
```

and then reimport. This time it worked but the two certificates were removed too. 
I also tried to import directly (without removal) but with a new alias name and it did work, but I'm not sure about the behavior of the server whtn the date of expiration of old certificate as that's why I need to update it. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. Thing is we can't just update one certificate in a chain. In my case, the three chained certificates are the certificate I'll use,  Root CA and intermediate CA associated to this certificate.

What I've done is exporting the Root CA and intermediate CA certificates from the renewed certificate and import them by using keytool with the order root -> intermediate -> renewed. Then when I check the content of .jks file, the corresponding certificate has been renewed.